# How can I create a seamless blue sky fill with PS CS5?

Tags: photoshop, photoshop-cs5, sky

I have a panorama created from three separate images.  As a result of perspective, there's an area that I need to fill seamlessly to match existing deep blue sky:

[image]

I've tried content-aware fill but it doesn't really have enough to work with and pulls in pixel data from the building as well as blue sky.  I also tried using a gradient fill but there's enough variation horizontally at the sky edge that I can't get a good match.

Can anyone suggest how to fill the empty area so it matches the adjoining sky seamlessly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm guessing from your taks you are using Photoshop CS5. Doesn't photoshop CS5 have the nifty content aware deletion tool that works wonder with such things? Here's a [tutorial](http://www.photoshopessentials.com/photo-editing/cs5/new-features/fill-content-aware/page-2.php) on using it.

Comment: Interesting.... I did things slightly differently and got awful results, but using the technique in the tutorial link gave me perfect results.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It's not perfect but what I did was select a single line of pixels for the sky and stretched it to the frame boundaries. Then I simply brushed with the spot healing brush a couple of times to hide the compression artifacts.

http://img825.imageshack.us/i/93939553.jpg/